# Handwriting recognition API's for android applications

Tags: android, ocr, handwriting-recognition

Is there any good Handwriting recognition API to help develop application on Android Platform?  Google has released (around July 2012 http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/handwritinginput/index.html) a feature to use handwriting for search in touch screen devices it looks great, is there a possibility to get access to these API's for use in Android Apps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768664/recommendations-for-handwriting-recognition-libraries-packages-in-java          check this link..

Answer (score 5):

*** I'm Product Manager at Vision Objects ***

I guess that you'll be able to find what you're looking for on the developer forum of [Vision Objects](http://devforum.visionobjects.com).

We announced new APIs [2 weeks ago](http://www.visionobjects.com/en/media-and-community/news/bdd/actualite/60/titre/vision-objects-announces-first-cloud-based-handwriting-recognition-service-for-developers-october).

And you can have a look on our web demo [here](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: This perfectly matches what I was looking for, web service offering still looks neat and light. Have Signed up a developer account and waiting for a Key to try out this cloud based service, will update my findings once i get the key and try this out.

Comment: liramu, did you end up purchasing a copy of the Vision Objects SDK, and if so, did it meet your needs?

Comment: Sorry, but how do I actually get to any content from the links you posted? All I can find are useless datasheets and a forum which in a roundabout way suggests I fill out a long complicated form to some sales rep, which is definitely *not* what I am interested in doing.

Comment: The APi have moved [here](https://developer.myscript.com/) and changed a lot since last hanswer but still provid all what you need to add handwriting recognition in an android app

Answer (score 5):

The best solution for android handwriting recognition is Thulika application and Thulika Trainer
source code can be download from [here](https://github.com/sinujohn/ThulikaIME)

It is also avilable in [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.sinu.thulika).
The advantages of using this code is.

- The code is easy to understand.
- it uses [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog) neural network library.
- You can create your own character set using trainer application which is explained in the [link](http://sinujohn.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/training-the-thulika-keyboard/)
- Recognition is very fast (even in low memory device)

You have to note following while using thulika trainer

- download and use alpha.txt file from this [link](https://www.box.com/s/h905qszbsj27d2rdhoct).you can edit this text file. otherwise it will not load the letters.
- Engine file should be renamed as E_enginename and put in to the engine folder before clicking load letter .
  eg : E_english.