# Gesture character recognition

Tags: android, gesture

I use `Dio dictionary`, function gesture on screen get text to search 
[image]

Library that in Android can make to be the function of this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like a handwriting recognition library. It seems you want to enable the users to write something on the screen ,when app is ON and then you can convert it to text and use it. There are many existing questions which might help you find a handwriting recognition library. See:

[Handwriting recognition API's for android applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063345/handwriting-recognition-apis-for-android-applications?lq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768664/recommendations-for-handwriting-recognition-libraries-packages-in-java

You can also use [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) library to recognize handwriting. See:

[Tesseract handwriting with dictionary training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310287/tesseract-handwriting-with-dictionary-training)

I haven't used any so I am not sure which one is the best but I hope that these links help you.