# Stylus support in android devices

Tags: android, motionevent, stylus-pen

I need to support stylus API in Android.

I went through this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS)

I need to support all user inputs through stylus.Like, if user inputs a text in `editext` then he/she should not be prompted for keyboard or stylus area field.

I have one registration form that contains a square blocks in which user needs to input one character.So, what I need is suppose user enters "*A*" in first block through stylus then it should be added in that block but keyboard/stylus area ahould not be prompted to user.

Also went through this [link.](http://www.ask.com/explore/stylus-vs-digitizer-pens-2034)

Is that possible in android? The feature should work same as *Digitizer Pen*

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between finger, or stylus when it comes to touch events.

Comment: The first link you provided simply returns the tool used for a MotionEvent, provided through [getToolType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getToolType%28int%29). How do you suggest that a user provides text input without a keyboard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063345/handwriting-recognition-apis-for-android-applications

Comment: @PaulLammertsma : Just like a Digitizer pen works without keyboard.