# Character Recognition - how to?

Tags: java, android, canvas, ondraw

How to extract text/character from PaintView in Android Studio. Example if I draw A on the canvas in PaintView using the onDraw() method how will I get that A as a textview ?

Comment: Similar question (but 6 years old): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063345/handwriting-recognition-apis-for-android-applications

Answer (score 2):

First of all Android studio is an IDE :)

Secondly, Once you draw the character over your android phone, take that Bitmap and pass to 
 Firebase ML kit which is free if you are using in your mobile only. Once you pass the Bitmap, the ML kit will process and you will have your text. In the below link, they have provided plenty of easy examples as well.

[Recognize Text in Images with ML Kit on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text)

It is a just a generic solution but I hope this will work.

Let me know if you are having any other doubt/solution/questions .

Thankyou.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking ML kit should be the most preferred solution thanks for confirming